# Problems with extrusion and subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, extrude

i'am fairly new to Blender. I am trying to model a simple piano and i think i did a good job so far, however, when i added the subdivision modifier, i've got some weard shapes and i don't know how to fix them.
[image]

As shown in the picture, the face is caving in, but i thought it would connect to the upper side instead.
Can someone explain to me why this happens and maybe provide an solution?
Thx for the help.

Comment: there must be a gap or an inner face, also try to keep quads. Maybe share your file if you want us to have a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/